# _api/search/query title field changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, search-api, title

We are using the below URL to search the data.

> /_api/search/query?querytext='test''&selectproperties='UniqueId,
>   Title, OriginalPath, ServerRedirectedEmbedURL,
>   ServerRedirectedPreviewURL'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'&rowlimit=100&startrow=0

In the result for .doc files, the returned Title is not the title set up in SharePoint but the ones from the Doc files. Can we somehow force to get back the SharePoint title which is different?

Thanks

Comment: Does your document library have a title column?

Answer (score 0):

Since Title managed property has mapping several crawled properties including MetadataExtractorTitle, TermTitle and so on.

MetadataExtractorTitle is the title extracted from the body of Word documents and PowerPoint presentations. And TermTitle is the title of the item in SharePoint.

If you want to display the title of the item in SharePoint in the search query result, try to set TermTitle crawled property’s priority to 0 in the search service application and start a full crawl.

Reference: [Show more relevant Titles in search results in SharePoint 2013 plus some other improvements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/10/30/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements/)